# How to connect kafka with OPC?

Tags: apache-kafka, opc

I need to put data from `OPC-UA` into a topic in `kafka`.

I tried searching for connector or technology to accomplish this, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: I do not know for sure , but maybe Striim? https://www.striim.com/integrations/opc-ua-kafka/ .

Comment: yes, but the problem is that striim isnt open source.